How to expose built custom ROS message inside a container to host machine without sourcing the setup.py file outside the container?
I am working in a ROS1 environment. right now the container builds the package and runs source devel/setup.py which allows the messages to work within the container. the docker container is using --network=host so we can see the rostopic data. In a few of the topics we use a custom message type. I can't echo them from outside the container without getting the following:
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [foo_msgs/DetectedObjectArrayStamped]. Are your messages built?

I can get the standard messages outside the container. Any idea how I can expose the built custom message types outside of the container? Is there some flag in docker I can use?
